# break string into pieces and wrap each piece in html with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a content editable div to try and make tags. When the user presses return, I need to be able to select the previous text (but not the previous tags) and turn it into a new tag. A tag will be wrapped in , so an example would be:

```
<em>tag1></em><em>tag2</em>tag3--- // about to press enter for tag3
```

This is what I'm thinking so far:

```
$('#tags').keydown(function(e) {                    
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) { 
        paste('---'); // this adds a separator when the user presses enter
        var content = $(this).html();
        var newTag = // the text between the last </em> and ---
        newtag.wrapInEm(somehow);
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should separate the current tags from the new tag creation.

HTML

```
<div id='tags'>
  <span id='tag-list'></span>
  <span id='tag-new' contenteditable></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function($){
    var tags = ['tag1', 'tag2'];

    $('#tag-new').on("keydown", function(e) {                    
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) { 
            // if (!saveToDB) return;
            tags.push($(this).text());
            _renderTags();
            return false;
        } 
    });

    $('#tag-list').on("click", "em", function(e){
        // if (!deleteFromDB) return;
        var idx = tags.indexOf($(this).html());
        tags.splice(idx,1);
        _renderTags();
    });

    function _renderTags(){
        $('#tag-list').html("<em>" + tags.join("</em><em>") + "</em>");
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // loadTagsFromDB
        _renderTags();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to understand your question--there are a handful of typos and your html sample doesn't make any sense.

Nevertheless:
How about using the [.wrap(]http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) jquery function?

```
$('#tags'.keydown(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) { 
        $([selector for previous text]).text().wrap(<em></em>);
    }
});
```

Comment: ...and the jQuery selector for the previous **text** would be ?

Comment: give me some html or edit what you currently have, and I will give you a selector.  As your question stands, I would have no idea how to do that.